# Link from react-router-dom affecting my CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am beginner to react. I used tailwind CSS in my project. If I use `Link` component from `react-router-dom`, it changes my styling. Is there any way to fix it?

```
<div className='flex flex-wrap justify-center'>
  {books?.map((book, index) => (
    <Link to={"/home/"+book.key.replace('/works/','')} >
      <div  key={index} className=' bg-slate-100 w-72 p-2 m-5 mt-20 shadow-lg rounded-lg flex flex-col items-center transition-all hover:scale-105'>
        <img className='h-52 m-3 shadow-lg' src={book.cover_i ? `https://covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/${book.cover_i}-L.jpg` : coverNotFound} alt="book cover" />
        <div className='text-center'>
          <p className='font-bold text-lg'>{book.title}</p>
          <p className='font-semibold text-'>Author: {book.author_name}</p>
          <p className='font-medium'>First Published Year: {book.first_publish_year}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Link>
  ))}
</div>
```

Before using Link tag

[image: Before using Link tag]

After using Link tag

[image: After using Link tag]

Is there any solution using tailwind CSS? Also tried to add inline style as "inline".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explicitly stated what you deem to be "broken", but playing spot-the-difference between the supplied images, I'm going to assume that the undesired behavior is the fact that the cards are no longer visually equal height.

They were equal height before wrapping with `<Link>` because the `<div>`s with the background color were direct descendants of the horizontal flex layout. By default, `align-items: stretch` is applied, making the direct descendants (the `<div>`s) equal height (since this is the cross axis).

On the other hand, when wrapped with `<a>` elements (rendered from the `<Link>` components), the `<a>` elements become direct descendants of the horizontal flex layout, not the `<div>` elements. Thus the `<a>` elements are now of equal height,  but not the now inner `<div>` elements.

You could consider applying `height: 100%` to the inner `<div>` elements so that they take up the height of their parent `<a>` elements:

```js
const Link = ({ ...props, children }) => <a {...props}>{children}</a>

function App() {
  const books = [
    {
      key: 'foo',
      cover_i: '10415806',
      title: 'Microsoft Word 2010',
      author_name: 'Nita Hewitt Rutkosky',
      first_publish_year: '2011',
    },
    {
      key: 'bar',
      cover_i: '7052416',
      title: 'Tristan et Iseult: poème de Gotfrit de Strasbourg comparé à d\'autres poèmes sur le même sujet',
      author_name: 'Adolphe Bossert',
      first_publish_year: '1865',
    },
    {
      key: 'baz',
      cover_i: '13102914',
      title: 'Arts in the Third Reich',
      author_name: 'Peter Adam',
      first_publish_year: '1992',
    },
  ];
 
  return (
    <div className='flex flex-wrap justify-center'>
      {books.map((book, index) => (
        <Link key={index} to={"/home/"+book.key.replace('/works/','')} >
          <div className=' bg-slate-100 w-72 p-2 m-5 mt-20 shadow-lg rounded-lg flex flex-col items-center transition-all hover:scale-105 h-full'>
            <img className='h-52 m-3 shadow-lg' src={book.cover_i ? `https://covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/${book.cover_i}-L.jpg` : coverNotFound} alt="book cover" />
            <div className='text-center'>
              <p className='font-bold text-lg'>{book.title}</p>
              <p className='font-semibold text-'>Author: {book.author_name}</p>
              <p className='font-medium'>First Published Year: {book.first_publish_year}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Link>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

You could also consider applying the styling classes to the `<Link>` components instead:

```js
const Link = ({ ...props, children }) => <a {...props}>{children}</a>

function App() {
  const books = [
    {
      key: 'foo',
      cover_i: '10415806',
      title: 'Microsoft Word 2010',
      author_name: 'Nita Hewitt Rutkosky',
      first_publish_year: '2011',
    },
    {
      key: 'bar',
      cover_i: '7052416',
      title: 'Tristan et Iseult: poème de Gotfrit de Strasbourg comparé à d\'autres poèmes sur le même sujet',
      author_name: 'Adolphe Bossert',
      first_publish_year: '1865',
    },
    {
      key: 'baz',
      cover_i: '13102914',
      title: 'Arts in the Third Reich',
      author_name: 'Peter Adam',
      first_publish_year: '1992',
    },
  ];
 
  return (
    <div className='flex flex-wrap justify-center'>
      {books.map((book, index) => (
        <Link
          key={index}
          to={"/home/"+book.key.replace('/works/','')}
          className='bg-slate-100 w-72 p-2 m-5 mt-20 shadow-lg rounded-lg flex flex-col items-center transition-all hover:scale-105'
        >
          <img className='h-52 m-3 shadow-lg' src={book.cover_i ? `https://covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/${book.cover_i}-L.jpg` : coverNotFound} alt="book cover" />
          <div className='text-center'>
            <p className='font-bold text-lg'>{book.title}</p>
            <p className='font-semibold text-'>Author: {book.author_name}</p>
            <p className='font-medium'>First Published Year: {book.first_publish_year}</p>
          </div>
        </Link>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found simple solution.  LinkContainer from 'react-router-bootstrap' didn't affected my css